# Save to system dialog box in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

how to get the windows "Save as dialog box" on click of some button  in AngularJS? I need to give the facility to save the data in a div tag to a file the user wants in his system.

Comment: You can simply google this question, but nonetheless check out https://github.com/koffsyrup/FileSaver.js

Comment: @Ronnie FileSaver.js automatically downloads the wanted file. What if I want to open first the saveAs dialog box for me to rename and choose where I want to store the file?Thanks